# Callback "headerContext" not working in Tabulator 5.2

Tags: tabulator

Im using the headerContext-Callback on specific columns for the purpose of hiding/showing a set of additional columns. This worked fine in Tabulator 5.1.8 but somehow lost its functionality since I updated to version 5.2. Instead of calling the specified function it just opens the browsers default right-click-popup.

```
{title: exampleColumnGroup, columns:[
        {title:"exampleAdditionalColumn", field:"xxx", visible:false},
        {title:"exampleToggleColumn", field:"yyy", headerContext:headerClickfunc},
      ],},
```

Additional info: I chose to use a callback on specific columns instead of tableEvents because I couldn't get tableEvents to work in combination with ColumnGroups.

Any thoughts what im doing wrong or maybe overlooked some deprecated functionality?

**edit:**

i forgot to show an example of the function that should be called on rightclick:

```
function headerClickfunc(e, column){
  e.preventDefault();
  switch(column.getField()) {
  case "yyy":
  table.toggleColumn("xxx");
}};
```

Problem is, that this function is never called via headerContext:headerClickfunc since i upgraded to Tabulator 5.2

I can manage to get the function called via:

```
table.on("headerContext", function(e, column){
  headerClickfunc(e, column);
});
```

but in this case the colum.getField() results in "undefined" which is somehow related to the use of a columngroup (tested it whithout the use of columngroups which works fine).

**edit2:**

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/roman_lucas/y01da8ob/) of the not working Code (headerContext does nothing) with Tabulator 5.2.7

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/roman_lucas/ku60cmpL/56/) of the working code (headerContext calls the intended function) with Tabulator 5.1.8

The Code on both jsfiddles is exactly the same. Only difference is the version of tabulator.min.js i used as external ressource (via cdn-link in the ressoruces tab on the left).

Answer (score 0):

The `headerContext` option, is simply a click listener, if you want to prevent the default browser context menu from opening then you need to call the `preventDefault` function on the event

```js
{title:"exampleToggleColumn", field:"yyy", headerContext:function(e){
    e.preventDefault() ///prevent browser context menu from opening
}},
```

If you were using Tabulators built in [Menu System](http://tabulator.info/docs/5.2/menu#overview) then you should be using the `headerContextMenu` option, not the `headerClick` option.

Also the 5.2 release introduced the concept of `popups` to allow the built in triggering of custom popup elements. Checkout the [Popup Documentation](http://tabulator.info/docs/5.2/menu#popup-column) for more info on these

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually im already using e.preventDefault(). I provided additional details in the original question.

Comment: At this point I would suggest you put together a js fiddle as it looks like you have a complex usage case, the easiest way for us to understand your issue is to see it in action

Comment: Thanks again for your reply! i have added jsfiddle in the original question.

Comment: maybe any idea? :)